# jquery .load() page then parse html

Tags: jquery, load

I have used the line below in my app. But now I need to parse the html loaded before I show it. Whats the best way to get certain html elements.

```
$("#div").load("page.html");
```

Thanks

**UPDATED**

Now I am using this but having trouble geting the title attribute of a div with the id "div".

```
function get_title()
{
    $.get("test.html", function(data) {
        var data = $(data);
        var title = $("#div", data).attr("title");

        alert(title);
    });
}
```

The html in the var data looks like this.

```
<div id="div" title="title example">
<p>
    Content
</p>
<p>
    Content
</p>
</div>
```

Thanks again

Comment: Why do you need to parse the HTML?  If you only want part of the loaded code to be on the page, use a selector in the URL parameter.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the semi-equivalent expanded version of [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), like this:

```
$.get("page.html", function(data) {
  var data = $(data);
  //do something
  $("#div").html(data);
});
```

Note that calling [`.html(data)`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) in this case is just [a shortcut for](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L256) `.empty().append(data)`.

---

Or, if post-processing is an option, just use the [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) callback, like this:

```
$("#div").load("page.html", function() {
  $(this).find(".class").remove(); //just an example
});
```

Comment: @Nick Craver I have used get method but cannot get the title of a div named "title". How would I do this. Thanks

Comment: @moo - how you you mean "named"? What's the `<div>` tag look like?

Comment: @Nick Craver I have updated my 1st post. The id is "div" of the <div>

Comment: @moo - To get an attribute you need to search the response, since it isn't in the main document yet, for example: `$("#div", data).attr("title");`

Comment: @Nick Craver Thanks so far. OK i have added it and put the value into a alert for testing but im getting undefined in it :/

Comment: @moo - Do you have an example page we can see?  Also do you *need* this before the content is loaded?  My second "post-processing" option above would allow `$("#div")` to work...but you should use unique IDs, so that should differ from the element you're loading.

Comment: @Nick Craver I have updated my 1st post and this function is called onClick. Thanks

Comment: @moo - What does the `<div>` you're loading look like? Is that *all* that's in this loaded file? e.g. it's a root level element?

Comment: @moo - Try this: `$(data).filter("#div").attr("title");`

Answer (score 5):

Instead of calling `.load()`, you should call `$.get` to perform an AJAX request and manually process the response.

Answer (score 5):

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url:'your_url',
    type:'get',
    dataType:'html',
    success:function(data)
   { 
       var _html= jQuery(data);
       //do some thing with html eg: _html.find('div').addClass('red')
       jQuery('#target').html(_html);
   }
});
```