# Get all URLs from an external URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get all URLs from a page using jQuery to call them later on using `$.get()`. If they were on the same page as the script is included in, it would be no problem calling something like

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
    alert(links[i].href);
}
```

In this case I'd just use alert to check that the links were actually parsed.
But how can I do the same thing with an URL that is not the current page?
Any help would be appreciated. Maybe I'm missing something ridiculously simple but I am really stumped when it comes to anything JavaScript/JQuery related.

Comment: If not in current page mean not in document model

Comment: To access the content of a page on a different domain that page must be written to allow you to do so, its not possible (in the client) by default (Same Origin Policy)

Comment: Assuming it does, how would I go about that?

Comment: You would have to 1. `$.get()` the other page 2. use an HTML parser to parse the HTML source into a DOM-object 3. search that for links

Comment: Given that an arbitrary URL won't allow you to, see [jquery .load() page then parse html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856590/jquery-load-page-then-parse-html)

Answer (score 2):

Blatantly copying [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3856606/3803371) answer by [Nick Craver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13249/nick-craver) (go upvote it), but modifying it for your use case:

```
$.get("page.html", function(data) {
  var data = $(data);
  var links = data.find('a');
  //do stuff with links
});
```

Note that this will only work if the page you're hitting is set up for cross-origin request. If it isn't, you'll need to do the same with a Dom-parser from a backend server. Nodejs has some great options there, including [jsDom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom).

Answer (score 1):

You will have to get the other page via an HTTP request (`$.get` in JQuery achieves this), and then either go about converting that HTML into a DOM that JQuery can then traverse and find the `<a>` tags for you, <s>or use another method such as a regular expression to find all the links within the returned markup.</s>

**edit**: Probably don't actually use a regex unless you have a guaranteed HTML format and can guarantee the format of all `<a>` tags on the page. By this point, it's probably just easier to parse the HTML for real.

Comment: Please don not parse HTML with a regex! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Comment: It can be done if you can guarantee the markup format, but you are right probably just easier to parse the HTML for real and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Collect the current page URL using `window.location.href` and then match the same with the href of other "a" tags in the loop

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var thisHref = window.location.href;
for(var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
    templink = links[i].href;
    if (templink != thisHref){// if the link is not same with current page URL
        alert(links[i].href);
    }
}
```